# Commit on new branch isn't visualized

Tags: git

In terminal I'm running the following to visualize my commit history on multiple branches:

```
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

This works, but I'm not seeing what I think I should be seeing. I have two branches, my master and a feature branch I created, switched to, and then added to commits to. But I'm seeing the following:

```
* cde9a0b Commit on feature branch
* b4a9c14 Commit on feature branch
* b72185f Commit on master
```

Shouldn't the two commits on the feature branch be off to the right to visualize that they aren't part of the master branch? When I run a `git status` or a `git branch`, they both confirm I'm committing to the correct branch. Am I reading this wrong, or did I skip a step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing what you should be seeing because `feature` is created off of `master`

Try this to see the branches and other `ref`s:

```
git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate
```

This is the excerpt on what `--decorate` is from [`git log`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) man page:

> --decorate[=short|full|no]
>
> > Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown. If short is specified, the ref name prefixes refs/heads/,
> >     refs/tags/ and refs/remotes/ will not be printed. If full is
> >     specified, the full ref name (including prefix) will be printed. The
> >     default option is short.

Comment: Hey Floyd, thanks for your response. This makes sense when I run it (it shows that it's the feature branch) but I'm not understanding why branched commits (off master, as you said) are showing on the same line. Should I be branching off something else? The visualization is pretty confusing, at least compared to how I've learned this. Should the branches be created on the remote?

Comment: [This](http://pcottle.github.com/learnGitBranching/) is a good resource for learning more on branching. To see two diverse branches, checkout `master` and make another commit and then try running the original command in your question itself.